# Filter data based on multiple dropdown selection in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I have a requirement to filter data displayed in table based on selection of multiple dropdown options. I want to fetch data in table at once from rest api.

for e.g.

How can I achieve this in React? Sample example would be great

For e.g. structure would be like

```
 <select>
        <option>Test<option>
        <option>Test 1<option>
 </select>
 <select>
        <option>Test3</option>
        <option>Test4</option>
 </select>
  and so on.........

 <table>
        <tr>
             <td> Some name </td>
             <td> Other name </td>
             <td> Test </td>
        </tr> 
     and so on...... 
 </table>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What sort of data are you filtering on?

Comment: I can't catch what are you going to do in your codes? Could you explain in more detail about `data` you want to filter or something else?

Comment: I want data to be filtered when option in dropdown selected. For ex. if "Test" is selected from dropdown list then data in table containing records related to "Test" will be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By what i understood of your requirements. Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ck1pwk) example. You can extend this for as many criteria as you want.

Let me know if this was the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This will definitely help me in my scenario